# что делает данная строчка?

Tags: python, numpy, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

начинаю свое путешествие в нейросетях и пытаюсь понять, что конкретно выполняет данная строчка:

```
z.alpha = 1/((i/3 + 6000) *np.max([np.max(z.weights1),np.max(z.weights2),np.max(z.free_coef1[0]),np.max(z.free_coef2[0])]))
```

weight - веса, free_coef - свободные коеффициенты
интересует конкретно

```
np.max([np.max(z.weights1),np.max(z.weights2),np.max(z.free_coef1[0]),np.max(z.free_coef2[0])]))
```

Comment: А по контексту, где вы взяли эту строчку не понятно?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вопрос дополнен

Comment: Это ничего не изменило, вы просто обрезали начало строчки. Может поделитесь хотя бы ссылкой откуда вы взяли строчку?

Comment: Тот, кто ее написал вот так и без коммента — безжалостный человек ;)

Answer (score 5):

Сложно, конечно, вне контекста предположить, что делает данная строка с точки зрения логики. Однако с точки зрения назначения использованных функций могу сказать, что `np.max` [возвращает максимальное значение в массиве](https://pyprog.pro/statistics_functions/amax.html). Следовательно, в Вашем случае данная строка

```python
np.max([np.max(z.weights1),np.max(z.weights2),np.max(z.free_coef1[0]),np.max(z.free_coef2[0])]))
```

получает сначала максимумы массивов `z.weights1`, `z.weights2`, `z.free_coef1[0]` и `z.free_coef2[0]` (4 числа), потом из этих максимумов делает список, оборачивая их в `[]`, а потом находит максимум в данном списке (насчёт момента, когда список преобразуется в тип `np.array` точно сказать не могу), то есть максимум из этих четырёх чисел – максимум из максимумов – одно число, являющееся максимальным в данных массивах. Делается это ещё одним вызовом `np.max`.

P.S. Из названий переменных, а точнее, полей объекта `z`, могу предположить, что, с точки зрения смысла, данная строка находит максимальное значение из весов и свободных коэффициентов. Но это всего лишь предположение. О большем судить невозможно ввиду недостатка контекста.